# Express.js - how to reload page after inserting data to the database

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm totally new to node/express and I'm stucked with my problem - I have a form with a file input (xlsx)- after reading the file and serialize it I send it via axios to the backend.

**Here is the part I use to read the excel file and send it to the given endpoint:**

```
const inputXLSX = document.querySelector('#inputXLSX');
const submitXLSX = document.querySelector('#submitXLSX');

let selectedFile;

const readXLSXtoJSON = (file) => {

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

if(!file) reject(Error('Wystąpił błąd podczas pobierania pliku'));

    let fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.readAsBinaryString(file);
        fileReader.onload = (event) => {
            const data = event.target.result;
            const workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'binary'});
            let rowObj;
            workbook.SheetNames.forEach(sheet => {
                rowObj = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheet]);  
            });
            resolve(JSON.stringify(rowObj));
        }
})
}

if (inputXLSX) {
    inputXLSX.addEventListener('change', (event)=>{
        event.preventDefault();
        selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
        })  
}

if (submitXLSX) {
    submitXLSX.addEventListener('click', async (event)=>{
        event.preventDefault();
        try {
            const XLSXdata = await readXLSXtoJSON(selectedFile);
            if (XLSXdata) {
                axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/1.0/tokens', {
                    XLSXdata
                  })
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(Error);
            }
       })
}
```

**middleware function - only for inserting data to the database or return status 'fail'**

```
exports.importToken = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    Token.insertMany(JSON.parse(req.body.XLSXdata));
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      status: 'fail',
      message: 'Wystąpił bład podczas zapisywania tokenów do bazy',
    });
  }
  next();
};
```

**and the final function in the middleware stack:**

```
exports.showToken = async (req, res) => {
  const newTokensList = JSON.parse(req.body.XLSXdata);
  res
    .json({
      status: 'success',
      data: newTokensList,
    })
    .redirect(301, '/admin/tokens');
};
```

**in return I get** UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this problem was not to create any middleware but simply:

- await the `axios` post request
- add `preventDefault()` to prevent from submitting a form.
- add `window.location.reload()`

  ```
      submitXLSX.addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
          event.preventDefault();
          try {
              const XLSXdata = await readXLSXtoJSON(selectedFile);
              await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/1.0/tokens', { XLSXdata });
              window.location.reload(true);

          } catch (err) {
              console.log(Error);
          }
      })
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to `redirect` the response:

```
res
  .json({
    status: 'success',
    data: newTokensList,
  })
  .redirect(301, '/page_you_want'); // Here!
```

Comment: I've tried this and I got an error: (node:4524) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client. 

There must be a problem with my implementation somewhere. I tried to move the database insertion to the middleware before and in createToken only res.status(200) but I've received the same error.

Comment: @Matyas can you share the middleware's code? There isn't enough information here to give an informed answer

Comment: Yes, of course - I edited my original post with all my code. Thank you so much for your time.